# Will USB2.0 supply power enough for 3.5" HDD?

Tags: usb, sata, toshiba-hard-drive

I've got Toshiba DT01ACA050 500GB HDD. It is specified in HDD as **5v 420mA**,12v 420mA.Does this mean i can operate HDD with help of **USB to SATA** cable??

Comment: Most all usb to sata adapters come with a psu for the hard drive as mentioned by Big Chris.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No.** USB can only provide 5V. Any 3.5" HDD requires both 5V and 12V power rails - therefore a USB to SATA will not power the disk. You will require an external power source for the disk.

See the mains adapter in this image:

[image]